# to take away a tag that doesn't fit the question

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Somebody edited and added a new tag to my question. I think its not the right tag for that question. How can I delete the tag? I am new to this forum, and don't know myself around so good.

Answer (score 3):

Hover your mouse just to the right of the tags to see the "edit tags" option, or edit the question and remove the tag.

If you do not think the tag is correct, it may also be helpful to add a comment on your question asking why the tag was added and clarifying why you don't think it's appropriate.